# Custom map entry set - Is it possible?

Tags: java, dictionary

I am making a class that maps Strings to Integers. I want to be able to get the Integer associated with a particular String and iterate through the entries, which are defined as another class that implements `Map.Entry<String, Integer>`.

Currently I have this:

```
public class MyMap implements Iterable<MyEntry> {

private final Map<String, Integer> wrappedMap = 
    new HashMap<String, Integer>();

@Override
public Iterator<MyEntry> iterator() {
    return wrappedMap.entrySet().iterator();
}

    //more methods

}
```

It's not compiling because of a type mismatch even though MyEntry implements `Map.Entry<String, Integer>`.

Is there a way to make a custom implementation of Map.Entry? Is there an easier way to do this that I'm overlooking? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: More information is needed, when you say custom.. you're not mapping 1 -> "1" ... are you?

Comment: @Aidanc It's course names to the number of credits. I want to iterate through the Course object.

Comment: @ryanbwork I want to iterate through the entry not the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not compiling because MyEntry is not a part of the hashmap at all.  If you want to return a list of MyEntry then you need to copy the data elements into a MyEntry instance and load that into a collection.  Which is going to be slow and consume a considerable amount of memory.

It should be:

```
@Override
public Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> iterator() {
    return wrappedMap.entrySet().iterator();
}
```

The call to `entrySet()` returns a Set which contains the mappings in the hashmap.  So the iterator needs to iterate over `Entry` objects

Answer (score 2):

Why not use just a regular map?

```
Map<String, MyEntry> map = new HashMap<String, MyEntry>();
```

Then you iterator will be simply this:

```
Iterator<MyEntry> iter = map.values().iterator();
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though `MyEntry` implements `Map.Entry<K,V>`, it is not the case that an `Iterator<MyEntry>` implements `Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>>`. For a class like `Iterator`, that distinction doesn't make intuitive sense to a human being, so let's instead think of a `Box<E>` class, which has `.put(E)` and `.contains(E)` methods. Is a `Box<Dinosaur>` a subclass of `Box<Animal>`? You might think so, but that's not the case: in a `Box<Animal>` it's legal to call `.put(someMammal)`, but in a `Box<Dinosaur>` that is clearly illegal. Since `Box<Dinosaur>` can't support all actions that are legal on a `Box<Animal>`, it is definitely not a subclass and cannot be substituted in at will.

From the compiler's point of view, the same concern might apply to iterators, and so you can't overload `.iterator()` to return an object which is not an instance of `Iterator<K,V>`.